# Could anybody provide a more detailed explanation of a tangent equation in its general form?

Tags: calculus, definition, self-learning

In my textbook I'm currently at the topic of a tangent line to an ellipsis and hyperbola. And there I've encountered this statement:

*If a curve has an equation*

$$
y = f(x)
$$

*then an equation of a tangent line to it, which contains the point* $(x_0,y_0)$ *, where* $y_0 = f(x_0)$ *, could be written as*

$$
y - y_0 = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)
$$

Could anyone explain this in more detail, please? I really did not understand author's logic.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure the elliptic curves tag is appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should know that derivative has an geometric meaning which coresponds to inclination.

$$m=f'(x_0)$$ and the tangent line is passing through the points $(x_0,f(x_0))$ with inclination $m$. Thus,

$$m=f'(x_0)=\dfrac{y-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ we are done.

Comment: thank you, it just did not come to my mind that `'` symbol has a meaning of a derivative. And in the textbook this word was not mentioned

Comment: @user31683: you are welcome.